# Reason why the TodoMVC guide was removed from Ember 1.11 doc

Tags: ember.js, todomvc

A [commit](https://github.com/emberjs/guides/commit/687da3ec8ba1f5c4d424eeeb63e8778bc6ff1d66) in the guide repository removed the TodoMVC getting started guide from the documentation. Since there is currently no replacement for this really useful material, I am a bit lost.

Has the guide been removed because it was obsolete or can I still rely on it (doc of version 1.10 still has it) to start my Ember applications?

Thanks

PS: for those who looks for an updated version of the TodoMVC application, see [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/todo-mvc-guide-for-ember-1-11/7734)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it was removed because it was built using Ember App Kit, which has since been deprecated. For developers that are new to Ember, it'd be a very poor starting point because it is no longer recommended to build apps that way.  [`ember-cli`](http://ember-cli.com) is recommended for starting new Ember Applications.

Looking at the JSBin that is [linked](http://jsbin.com/gureki/1/embed?html,css,js,output) from that commit, you can see how old it is in the console:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.8
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

[Ember 1.0.0-rc.8](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc.8) was released Aug 28, 2013.  Ancient..!

Check out this [video walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tonV3G2cPrA) by [@RyanLaBouve](https://twitter.com/RyanLaBouve) that shows how to build TodoMVC using `ember-cli`.  Much of the code can still be used from the original, but this shows how to utilize it using `ember-cli`.

Comment: Thanks for the intel. I saw that ember-cli guys have their own version of the application to: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-todos